# How do I get even lighting across a model? Blender 2.82

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, lighting

I want to texture bake, but the lighting causes the final product of the bake to be affected with dark areas. How do I get even lighting across the model or fix the problem in general?

Comment: Can we get some visuals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn up the value of the world's color.

Say we start with some object that I have a few lights on, but in an otherwise empty scene;

[image]

I turn off my collection of lights, then make the color of the world shader pure white;

[image]

Result;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get even lighting across your whole model you could use a very big plane with an emission shader, so the shadows will be minimized. Or you use a hdri-Environment with just a white image, so it creates an even light-dome around your model. Another solution could be just one color solid white for the environment. All the best Marco